# I have trouble with Interpreter in Pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, interpreter

I am python newbie. I am doing 1 project testing of Keras. I already installed `opencv` by `pip install opencv-python` but i can't find `opencv` in `interpreter` of `Pycharm` and have an error when i `import cv2`. My interpreter is `usr/bin/python2.7`

Comment: probably not the same python installation.

Comment: I don't understand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project interpreter settings in preferences in Pycharm, and use the + sign there to add the module to your interpreter.

This can happen when pip is installing to a directory that is not part of your project's python interpreter's PATH.

Installing via the Pycharm preferences menu always solves for me, although there is a deeper issue of pip not installing to the correct directory...