# ImportError: No module named pandas [pycharm]

Tags: python, pycharm

I am just starting to use pycharm. I want to use tabula-py, when I try to import tabula it gives me the following error:

```
import tabula
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm 
CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, 
in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tabula/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .wrapper import read_pdf
  File "/Applications/PyCharm 
CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, 
in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tabula/wrapper.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Applications/PyCharm 
CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, 
in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

and when i try to import pandas it's the same error. How do I fix this?

Output from `pip`:

> Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from python)

Comment: Have you tried `pip install pandas`?

Comment: Yes it says "Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have trouble with Interpreter in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314549/i-have-trouble-with-interpreter-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error says

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
packages`

But your pip says

`/Users/Rexon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`

Make sure your terminal and pycharm use the same python path.

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm, go to preferences, and then project interpreter and click the '+' button to add the library to your project interpreter.

Your project $PYTHONPATH environment variable does not include the directory that pip installed your module to.

Comment: I have my project interpreter set as 2.7.13 and it includes the following packages,"certifi", "chardet", "idna", "numpy", "pandas", "pip", "python-dateutil", "pytz", "requests", "tabula-py", "wheel"

Comment: Can you show the path of project interpreter used for this project here?